# rules written by (the) existing players: article usage

Tags: articles, determiners, zero-article

A quote from The Economist ([Higher education: The attack of the MOOCs](http://www.economist.com/news/business/21582001-army-new-online-courses-scaring-wits-out-traditional-universities-can-they?spc=scode&spv=xm&ah=9d7f7ab945510a56fa6d37c30b6f1709)):

> “Anyone who thinks the rules of engagement have already been written
>   by the existing players is massively underestimating the potential of
>   the technology,” he says.

May the definite article be omitted before "existing players", or is the word "existing" a modifier that makes THE obligatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of *existing* before *players* has no bearing on whether or not to use the article.

> ... the rules of engagement have already been written by **the** existing
>   players ...

implies that the rules have been written by all of the existing players.

On the other hand:

> ... the rules of engagement have already been written by existing
>   players ...

tells the reader only that existing players have written the rules, but not necessarily all existing players.

Comment: Thanks, Shoe! Would the second sentence imply that the rules are written by existing players in general, with some not participating but giving their tacit agreement and complying with the rules?

Comment: IMHO, all players rarely participate in writing rules, many  passively accept those written by some group, that's why I'm unsure why the author has chosen to use THE.

Comment: The first part of your assumption is correct, but I don't think you can go beyond that to infer tacit approval of all existing players. Similarly, if I read: _This website has been made by current students_, I can infer only that some current students participated in the project. I cannot assume anything beyond this.

Comment: In reply to your second comment, it is indeed confusing for the writer to use the definite article unless he or she was referring to a distinct subset of existing players already identified or known to the reader.

Comment: Thank you, Shoe! There are 2 possibilities in my mind now: 1. The author may have meant either all the existing players (if no subset is mentioned prior to the sentence) or a subset of existing players (if such a subset is mentioned just prior to the sentence). 2. Or, putting the THE, he\she still means "all the existing players", but introducing the reader to some or subset of them first makes the use of THE less bumpy to the reader. (most likely IMHO)

Comment: @CopperKettle I'm fairly certain the author does intend to refer to *all* the existing players. I agree it is unlikely that every player had a hand in writing the rules, but that's not the point: the author is making a distinction between *all the currently existing players*, who he thinks do *not* have a monopoly on the writing of the rules, and the newcomers who haven't yet come to the technology. I'd have used the article as well.

Comment: Wendi, thank you very much! So THE underscores the author's point, adds emphasis (incumbents vs. newcomers). Great.